# Change Default table to other table - JWT Token Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have laravel 5 version running backend and I had used jwt token, by default it uses Users table and now i want that to  be changed to contacts table, so they can login through contact credentials. I have referred JWT multi-auth procedures. I want to know the step by step process to change the default guard and the default table for jwt token.

Comment: What package are you using for JWT?

Comment: Using  "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12" and laravel 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue after some research. Hope it helps to others. find the below changes

Changed Code in config/auth.php and Changed guards.

```
  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'contacts',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'contacts',
        ],
    ],
```

Also Change providers.

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'contacts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Contacts::class,
        ],

    ],
```